# Nested node-modules folder inside npm folder

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have 2 node modules folders

```
c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
```

Is this normal?  If not, what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is perfectly normal. To view your whole dependency tree of global node modules you can run `npm list -g`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: @wayne.blackmon anytime